# How to setup the content of a HTTP::Request with form data in PERL

Tags: perl, http, post

I would like to send form data via the http post method. Therefore I would like to setup a `HTTP::Request` with the appropriate data, but I do not know how to do this. I would like to do something like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Headers;
use HTTP::Request;

my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $header = HTTP::Headers->new();
my $data;

# What I have to do here to initialize $header and $data
# with name=Pete and age=35 for example 

my $request = HTTP::Request->new( POST, "http://www.example.com", $header, $data );

my $response = $browser->request( $request );

say $response->as_string();

exit;
```

I have not found any full example using HTTP::Request yet. Using LWP::Simple is out of question.

Comment: You may want to look into WWW::Mechanize, which is a wrapper around LWP::UserAgent that makes it very easy to do POSTs and other common tasks.

Answer (score 3):

You can supply form values to the `post` method of your `LWP::UserAgent` object. From the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#ua-post-url-form):

> **$ua->post( $url, \%form )**
>
> **$ua->post( $url, \@form )**
>
> **$ua->post( $url, \%form, $field_name => $value, ... )**
>
> **$ua->post( $url, $field_name => $value,... Content => \%form )**
>
> **$ua->post( $url, $field_name => $value,... Content => \@form )**
>
> **$ua->post( $url, $field_name => $value,... Content => $content )**
>
> This method will dispatch a POST request on the given `$url`, with `%form` or `@form` providing the key/value pairs for the fill-in form content.

As with the `get` method, you can generate additional headers by passing them as name/value pairs. The following will `POST` the form data in `%form` and set the `Cookie` header:

```
my %form = (
    foo    => 'bar',
    answer => 42
);

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->post( 'http://www.example.com', Cookie => $cookie, \%form );
```

This actually uses [`HTTP::Request::Common`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request::Common)'s `POST` function behind the scenes to generate the request. The `HTTP::Request::Common` documentation has [examples](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request::Common#POST-url) of how to generate more complex requests.

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for. I need full control over the `HTTP::Request` and I am interested in full details.

Comment: What do you mean "full control"? You can also set headers in the `post` method so I don't know what else you need.

Comment: Also, note that `LWP::UserAgent` uses [`HTTP::Request::Common`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request::Common) to generate the request, so anything you can add to an `HTTP::Request::Common` POST request, you can add to an `LWP::UserAgent` `post`.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP::Request is a subclass of [HTTP::Message](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP%3a%3aMessage). I think that's where you will find the methods that you want.